# Squid. Vendor preset, how to enable it?

Tags: server

`systemctl status squid` reports:

```
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/squid.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled).
```

Answer (score 3):

It is already enabled. `vendor preset: disabled` means that the default upon installation is to keep it disabled, but it seems to have been `enabled` afterwards. There's no need to change the `vendor preset`, and to change it you'll need to rebuild the package.